# How to get the location of the mouse on a page when I press a key without any operation of the mouse?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the location of the mouse when I press a key, and I use this `document.addEventListener('keydown',function(event)` , I do not know how to get the location of the mouse without any operation of the mouse. Then I try to use `document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e)` before that, it works, but the console logs of keycode and mouse location show many times in developer tools.

How to get the location of the mouse on a page when I press a key without any operation of the mouse or execute one time if use mousemove event.

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    document.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
        var keynum;
        if(window.event) // IE
        {
            keynum = event.keyCode;
        }
        else if(event.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        {
            keynum = event.which;
        }
        console.log(event.keyCode)

        if(keynum==79&&event.altKey){
          console.log(e.pageX+","+e.pageY)
        }
    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSXBV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done.

[segmentfault.com/q/1010000022862020](https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000022862020)

```
let mouseEvent = null

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  // console.log('mousemove', e)
  mouseEvent = e
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  console.log(e, mouseEvent)
})
```